# How to convert curved features into geojson

Tags: ogr2ogr, shapely, mapguide, curved

I'm using a MapGuide system which provides some CURVEPOLYGON(s).

Using python shapely's [loads()](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html?highlight=loads#shapely.wkt.loads) raises a `WKTReadingError`.

Tried to find a tool that can approximate curved shapes into a polygon (as a set of points) but no luck.

I suspect [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to be able to do this (not sure if I'm stupid) but wasn't able to do so...

Has anyone been successful when dealing with such shapes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're on the right track. Curved geometries were brought into GDAL/OGR 2.x. You can approximate curved geometries as a linear geometry. Both OGR and Shapely can export as a GeoJSON-like `dict` (via `mapping`):

```
from osgeo import ogr
from shapely import wkb
from shapely.geometry import mapping

# Import as an OGR curved geometry
wkt_in = 'CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(1 3, 3 5, 4 7, 7 3, 1 3))'
g1 = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt_in)

# Approximate as linear geometry, and export to GeoJSON
g1l = g1.GetLinearGeometry()
geojson_out = g1l.ExportToJson()

# Or transfer to shapely, then export as GeoJSON
g2 = wkb.loads(g1l.ExportToWkb())
geojson_dict = mapping(g2)
```

[image: wkt_out]

Comment: God bless you @Mike! Works perfectly. Except for the installation of the `gdal` package, but that's another story... ;)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the GDAL library?